# C-m-% keybindings for navigating parenthesis in emacs in iTerm2 on OSX

Tags: emacs, scheme, sicp

Im using Emacs 26.1 on my OSX Mojave machine. I run emacs in iTerm2 terminal. Control key was working fine but I had to map the left option key and right option key to Esc+, to get the Meta key to work.

Im writing scheme code in emacs and i want to be able to navigate over parenthesis by using keybindings like C-m-n to directly go from on opening parenthesis to after the corresponding closing parenthesis as given on https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Moving-by-Parens.html . But C-m-% commands are not working as C-m is adding a new line. How can i get the C-m-% commands to work in emacs in iTerm2 ?

Thanks

Comment: You want to use `Control-Meta-p` not `Control-<the letter m>-p`. In the Emacs documentation, when describing key bindings, `M` is always `Meta` (unless it specifically says otherwise.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That worked :)